# Multiple atributes in JQuery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in `JQuery` and this function adding values if checkbox is checked but I would like to ignore if checkbox is disabled. Is it possible to add this in one statement?

```
 $('.group:checked').each(function(i, e) {
...
```

Can i add `.is(':enabled')` somewhere  in line above?

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, two tops, and it repays you that time almost immediately.

Comment: Youcan also use `$().filter()`, read information here: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the [`:enabled` selector](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/):

```
$('.group:checked:enabled').each
```

Comment: @Klapsius: Ah, yeah, that would get the *union* of the two, not the intersection. :-)